# what is the meaning of "to get on board"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Would you please tell me what it means to say "to get on board" in the following sentence?

> Nothing **gets** the organization **on board** quicker than clearly demonstrating the real impact of value pricing.

Comment: We can tell you, but I'm guessing that you question will be more likely to get upvoted and less likely to be downvoted if you share the results of your research effort. I'd expect to at least see the meaning of "on board" you found when you looked this up in a dictionary.

Comment: [take sth on board](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-sth-on-board) *to understand or accept an idea or a piece of information*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone gets onboard a ship, they are agreeing to go on the voyage with the rest of the crew. So, by analogy, when we say that people are "on board" when they agree to go participate in any adventure or enterprise. Just as getting on board a ship mean that you agree to go where the ship is going and to support the rest of the crew in meeting the perils of the journey, so "getting on board" with a project means that you agree to the direction and promise to help.

Comment: Agree, but would add there's an unconvivial, slightly coercive/cultish connotation to "get on board", as those who are not *onboard* would be *left behind*, while those *onboard* presume themselves to be going in the *right direction*.

Comment: Absolutely. Some people got whacked on the back of the head and woke up on their way to Australia. People get press ganged on board in the corporate world today as well. Some, on the other hand, are eager to get on board. The phrase, both in its origins and its modern usage seems to cover both the happy volunteer and the reluctant conscript.

Answer (score 2):

To *get someone [on board](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+board)* here means to **get someone's co-operation or support**.

So the example sentence means

> Clearly demonstrating the real impact of value pricing is the most effective way to ensure support from the organization.

Comment: As it currently stands, Chris, this answer isn't unfortunately anything more than a dictionary definition. I would've appreciated if you didn't answer a question that might be answerable by a dictionary, but what is done is done. Please cite some sources, add more usage examples etc.

Comment: I wonder if it means anything (here: clearly demonstrating the real impact of value pricing) that (helps) place(s) the organization in its correct direction toward its aim.

Comment: @morteza I added a paraphrase of your sentence. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

To;

> get on board,

is a some what informal phrase that means; To agree with a course of action or opinion. [urban dictionary top description](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20on%20board)

> "It's a new approach and we want everyone to get on board and make it happen."

A similar phrase would be;

> "It's a new approach and we want everyone to **jump in** and make it happen."